# How to append a prefix to a flask blueprint that already has a blueprint?

Tags: python, api, flask, endpoint, prefix

I'm using flask application factories so I'm using blueprints across multiple modules such as `user.py`, `track.py` and `weather.py`. Each of these would have a separate endpoint such as `/user/`, `/track/` etc.

I'm doing that by adding a prefix when registering the blueprint like so:

```
def register_blueprints(app):
    """
    Registers all blueprints
    """
    app.register_blueprint(user_bp, url_prefix='/user/')
    app.register_blueprint(track_bp, url_prefix='/track/')
...
```

So each blueprint have a url_prefix, but I want another prefix `/v1/` to be appended to these prefixes so it should be something like `/v1/user/`, `/v1/track/`, etc.

I have tried adding the outside prefix where the Blueprint object is initialized and then tried adding a prefix when registering the blueprint, but that overwrites the prefix instead of appending it.

So far the only solution I've come up with is as follows:

```
prefix = '/v1'
...
def register_blueprints(app):
    """
    Registers all blueprints
    """
    app.register_blueprint(user_bp, url_prefix=f'{prefix}/user/')
    app.register_blueprint(track_bp, url_prefix=f'{prefix}/track/')
```

Is there a better way of achieving this instead of f strings?